# acts_as_follower order followers in descending order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am using the [gem acts_as_followers](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ftcocca%2Facts_as_follower&ei=jGIkVLT2LqaIsQTuo4G4Ag&usg=AFQjCNEDKLqGtycwHSk6s1F4kQ50m3W8qg&sig2=FYdqL3YwdhV1UCP--JP_Yw&bvm=bv.76247554,d.cWc) to enable people to follow other users on my site.  When I use the following:

```
@user.following_users
@user.user_followers
```

I'd like to return an array containing users ordered by their follow date.  Right now, it seems like the default ordering is oldest first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you could try `@user.following_users.descending` or pass option to this methods, like: `@user.user_followers(order: {created_at: :desc})`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but this didn't work for me – I got the same response even if I changed it to ascending